# Using expansion files for android wear watchfaces

Tags: wear-os, android-wear-data-api, apk-expansion-files

I am working a watch face everything works is fine but the problem is apk has crossed 100 MB (80% of space is because of image resources). So i m in a situation to use the expansion file. Have added the image resource as expansion file & i can now access the images in my handheld without any error. Now my question is how do i send my 80MB(around 500 images) to wear devices & use the images in my watch face. Is using the expansion file a good idea, am i in the right path or please suggest me a way to use my 100+ MB apk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution to this issue. But not sure whether this is possible before wear 2.0,for 2.0 when uploading the wear apk, we can upload a expansion file for wear too. We can follow the same procedure, we use for handheld expansion file.